# Create the [nivo-slider] tag and merge [nivo], [nivoslider] with it

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I would like to consolidate [nivo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivo) and [nivoslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivoslider) into a new [nivo-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivo-slider). Nivo Slider is technically two words and the existing [nivoslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivoslider) doesn't follow our naming convention (as pointed out by @doppelgreener below). I cannot create the new tag with the hyphen because it is too similar to the version without it.

**Can somebody add the tag [nivo-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivo-slider) so I can begin to go through these questions and retag them?**

The existing [nivo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivo) and [nivoslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivoslider) will need to be made synonyms of the new tag.

**EDIT:** This is still an issue that has ***not been addressed after a whole year***! I would like to begin migrating the ~400 questions to a new [nivo-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivo-slider), however it cannot be created because it is too similar to the non-hyphenated version. Can a moderator please create the new, hyphenated tag so I may begin migrating these questions to the new tag?

[image]

Comment: Bump. This issue still needs to be addressed.

Comment: I came here to request the same thing and found this request already posted nine months ago.  We need to take care of this as the tag usage is almost evenly split between [tag:nivo] and [tag:nivoslider], and both with identical descriptions.  At the very least, these should be merged or synonym-ized.

Comment: @Sparky Good luck, I've put on bounty on this. I've edited it a dozen times, trying to bring attention to it and no one seems to want to take the 5 seconds to create a new tag.

Comment: Seems like a task for a moderator.

Answer (score 13):

Beyond that, [Nivo Slider](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/) is two words, so by convention, the tag should really be [nivo-slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nivo-slider). We don't drop spaces in names in tags, we hyphenate them.

Comment: Excellent point.